# NopCommerce google bot and facebook crawl redirected through login page

Tags: nopcommerce

I have nopCommerce website and when testing in Facebook Sharing Debugger, it shows canonical url as "/login?ReturnUrl=%2F". Also Google Search Console says that my sitemap is not valid XML but a HTML page - I think google bots are also redirected to login page.

[Facebook Sharing debugger screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SgkR.png)

[Google Search Console screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoBPU.png)

My ACL Public Store rules are all set to enabled for customers and as you can see, you can visit all the pages without loging in.
Why are google and facebook bots redirected through login page? How can I fix this?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I checked those db records and everything looks ok. Do you have any other suggestion? My website stopped being crawled. Thank you. Did you solve your issue?

Comment: I am having the same issue. I checked those db records and everything looks ok. Do you have any other suggestion? My website stopped being crawled. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to make sure that table [Customer_CustomerRole_Mapping] has two records:

```
Customer_Id | CustomerRole_Id
      2     |       4
      3     |       4
```

These represent permissions for search engine crawlers and etc.
So these records give them same permissions as Guest.

Comment: -1

I am having the same issue. I checked those db records and everything looks ok. Do you have any other suggestion? My website stopped being crawled. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your **Search engine friendly page name** filed in all pages that included in your sitemap.xml
there's always a missed SEname filed in pages like content management, products, manufacturers, blogs and etc.
if you have plenty of URLs inside your sitemap and it's hard to find it you can disable/enable below options in **https://yoursitename.com/Admin/Setting/GeneralCommon**

> Sitemap includes categories

> Sitemap includes manufacturers

> Sitemap includes products

To find which of these pages have a missed SEname filed.
If this solution does not help you, you should use a query to find which pages does not have SEname field.